# ncover merge reports

Tags: .net, merge, ncover

we are using NCover from http://www.ncover.com/
For our application we have 6 different solution and we create report for each solution.
In NCover explore there is MergeData option which I can use to merge all Coverage.xml.

But I want some functionality from command line which I can use in NANT script, has anybody got any idea how to do that

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line tool which you could execute from nant:

http://www.kiwidude.com/blog/2006/10/ncoverexplorer-merging-ncover-reports.html

Answer (score 0):

if you place multiple coverage files on the command line, NCover Reporting should merge them all together, and then you can use the "//s " argument to save the merged result